# DDEV, Drupal 9, CiviCRM & Civix Installation

Tags: civicrm-buildkit, civix, drupal-9

Thanks is advance. I am using DDEV with Drupal 9.5.2 and CiviCRM 5.57.2
I would like to use civix to look at custom reports.
Any advice on how to install it? I've look at the documentation but most of it is for installing on local machine, which is not what I use.

Best A.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SearchKit to build your report? Going forward Searchkit is a way to build reports. We understand complex logics are not handled in Searchkit atm but if its simple report SearchKit is a best option over custom reports.

Custom reports:

1. You will need to install [Civix](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/)
2. Create [extension using civix](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-module)
3. Create [report using civix command](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-module)

Comment: Another option since you are using Drupal might be to use CiviCRM Entity plus Drupal Views. Not all tables are accessible this way but it does provide some additional options, and especially if you are more familiar with Drupal Views dev than CiviCRM dev might give you a quicker easier way to get you what you need.